# How can I extract variable from ODE function calculating BVP?

Tags: matlab, ode

I am solving BVP using bvp4c in Matlab. I need to save extra variable data in ODE function.

I already used this method:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/312549-get-variable-out-of-ode-45

But it doesn't save to Workspace after my BVP solution is done.

```matlab
function dydt = myODE(t,y,p)

u = pi^2/tf^2*(p(1)+p(2))*sin(pi*t/tf);

for i = 2:5
   u = u - (i*pi/tf)^2*p(i-1)*sin(i*pi*t/tf);
end

persistent u_save
switch t
    case 'init'
        u_save = u;
    case ''
        u_save = [u_save; u];
    case 'done'
        assignin('base','u_save',u_save);

end

dydt = [y(3) y(4) u 0];

... Equations for my model ...


end
```

I would love to save my input data that are represented in variable `u`. I  need this input data represented in my results.

Comment: Are you trying to return multiple values? If so, then just have your function call like this: `function [dydt u] = myODE(t,y,p).` However, in your main script, when you call `myODE`, you will have to call it like this:  `[dydt,u] = myODE(t,y,p)`.

Comment: `t` is a floating point value for the time. Why do you expect that you can compare it to a string? The BVP solver is iterative, it solves a high-dimensional nonlinear system of equations. You should at least save pairs of t and u to be able to get any sensible interpretation. Does u depend on y at all?

Comment: in the script I call for my function as 
`sol = bvp4c(@myODE, @odeBC, solinit, options);`
I am stuck here, because this isnt ordinary ODE function, yet BVP solver that I do not know how he uses with my functions.